# How to combine several PNG images as layers in a single XCF image?

Tags: png, gimp, gimpfu, xcf

I have several PNG images, which I need to combine as individual layers in a new GIMP XCF image. I need to perform this task many times, so a script based solution would be best.

So far i tried to play around with the batch mode of GIMP, but failed miserably.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of script-fu, which uses Scheme, I'd recommend using  the GIMP-Python binding for this, since it is far easier to manipulate files and listings.

If you check `filters->Python->Console`  you will b dropped into an interactive mode - at the bottom of it, there will be a "Browse" button which lets you select any of GIMP's procedures in its API and paste it directly in this console.

There is as an API call to "load a file as a layer" - `pdb.gimp_file_load_layer` -

this however, brings the image to memory, but do not add it to the image - you have to call
`pdb.gimp_image_insert_layer` afterwards

You can type this directly in the interactive console, or,check one of my other GIMP-related answers, or some resource on GIMP-Python on the web to convert it to a plug-in, which won't require pasting this code each time you want to perform the task:

```
def open_images_as_layers(img, image_file_list):
    for image_name in image_file_list:
        layer = pdb.gimp_file_load_layer(image_name)
        pdb.gimp_image_insert_layer(img, layer, None, 0)

img = gimp.image_list()[0]
image_list = "temp1.png temp2.png temp3.png"
open_images_as_layers(img, image_list.split())
```

The second to last line `img = ...` picks a needed reference to an open image 
in GIMP - you could also create a new image using pdb calls if you'd prefer
(example bellow).
The file list is a hardcoded space separated string in the snippet above,
but you can create the file list in any of the ways allowed by Python.
For example, to get all the ".png"  file names in a
`c:\Documents and Settings\My user\Pictures`  folder, you could do:

```
from glob import glob
image_list = glob("c:/Documents and Settings/My user/Pictures/*png")
```

To create an image programatically:

```
img = gimp.Image(1024, 768)
pdb.gimp_display_new(img)
```

Comment: Whow, great, I think this will do it for me!

Comment: Is "gimpfu" strictly for Scheme? Many Python plugins for GIMP seem to include `from gimpfu import *` so I'm a little confused as to how I should be using these terms: script-fu, gimp-fu, plugin, ...

Comment: Thre is a Python Module in the GIMP Python bindings called `gimpfu` - I've confused it for `scriptfu` which is the name given for scripts in scheme, usually